# Text behavior inside div

Tags: html, css

I have text inside a `<div>` WITHOUT a border property.

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="second"></div>
    <p>TEXT</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#second {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background:red;
    float:left;
}

#main {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

My text aligns as shown in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/mindaugo/vvw9ajh0/)  at the top with other div. 
When I add CSS border property to DIV, pharagraph has margin applied - [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/mindaugo/3dzxjqsp/6/)

Why does it happen?

Comment: This is due to collapsing margins. Without the `border` the default   `margin` applied to the `p` spills out of the `div`. With the border the `margin` is contained within the `div`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's unexpected behavior is coming from using `float:left;` only to one div. If you use float for p also then you'll not get different behavior.

[Check this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3dzxjqsp/7/) : toggle border on/off.

From the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats):

> A floated box is shifted to the left or right until its outer edge touches the containing block edge or the outer edge of another float. If there is a line box, the outer top of the floated box is aligned with the top of the current line box.
>
> If there is not enough horizontal room for the float, it is shifted downward until either it fits or there are no more floats present.